# Orthogonal Subspace

Tags: functional-analysis

I got stuck in a problem of Haim Brezis's book:

> Let $E:= l^1$. Consider $N := c_0$ as a closed subspace of $E^{\star} := l^{\infty}$.
>
> Denote
>   $$N^{\perp}:= \{x \in E: \langle f,x \rangle=0,\forall f \in N\}$$
>   and 
>   $$N^{\perp\perp}:= \{f \in E^{\star}: \langle f,x \rangle=0,\forall x \in N^{\perp}\}.$$
>
> Prove that $N \subsetneq N^{\perp\perp}$.

I know that we have to find a $f_0 \in E^{\star}$ such that $f_0 \in N^{\perp\perp}$ but $f_0 \notin N$, but I don't know the way to construct $f_0$.

Can you show me some idea of constructing?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Hint: let $e_i=(0,\ldots, 0, 1, 0,\ldots)\in c_0$ for $i=1,2,\ldots$, then what can you say about $N^{\perp}$? What is $N^{\perp\perp}$?

Comment: Some restrictions are necessary. If  $N=E^*$ then $N^{\bot}$ is empty and $N^{\bot \bot}=E^*=N.$ What does $N:=c_0$ mean ?

Comment: @user254665 $c_0$ is the subspace of $\mathscr l^\infty$ consisting of sequences converging to $0$. For this specific example you have that $N^{\perp\perp}\supsetneq N$, not in general.

Answer (score 1):

$c_0$ is the space of sequences converging to $0.$

Theorem: $\;l_1=c_0^*.$

Proof: Let $\delta_{a,b}$ be the Kronecker delta. That is, $\delta_{a,b}$ is $1$ if $a=b,$ and is  $0$ if $a\ne b.$ $$\text {For } j\in \mathbb N \text { let }  c(j)=(\delta_{j,n})_{n\in \mathbb N}.$$ $$\text {For  }  f\in c_0^* \text { let } \bar f =(\;f(c(j))\;)_{j\in \mathbb N}.$$ To deal with the case of complex sequences as well as real sequences, $$\text {for }  j\in \mathbb N \text { let } a_j\in \mathbb C \text { with }  |a_j|=1  \text { and }  a_jf(c(j))=|f(c(j))|.$$

For $j,k\in \mathbb N$ let $e_{j,k}=a_j$ if $j\leq k$ and $e_{j,k}=0$ if $j>k.$ Then $e(k)=(e_{j,k})_{k\in \mathbb N}\in c_0$ with $\|e(k)\|_{c_0}=1$. And we have $$\|f\|\geq  |f(e_k)|=|\sum_{j\leq k}a_jf(c(j))|=\sum_{j\leq k}|f(c(j))|.$$ Therefore $\bar f\in l_1.$

Let $S$ be the subset of $c_0$ of all sequences $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ such that $x_n=0$ for all but finitely many $n$. Then $S$ is dense in $c_0$. And $f(x)=$<$x,\bar f$> for all $x\in S.$ Therefore,as members of $c_0^*$. we have $f=\bar f.$ (End of proof).

So with $N=c_0$ we  have $N^{\bot}=\{f\in N^*:\forall x\in N\;(f(x)=0)\}=\{0\},$ so $N^{\bot \bot}=\{0\}^{\bot}=l_1^*=l_{\infty}\supsetneqq c_0=N.$